# Binding to a relations property in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm new in Core Data, and i got a problem i can't get my head around how to do "the right way"

I'll try and examplify my problem.

I got a entity Car. And a list of all the cars in my program. The cars have some attributes, but they are not predefined. So for each car i want to be able to define some properties. 
Therefore i have defined a new entity CarProperty, with a one to many relation with the car.

In the nscollectionview i would like to show some of the properties from the car, more specefic the number of kilometer (numKm) it has driven (if that property exist). So i want to bind it to a label. But how to do?

I can't say `representedObject.properties.numKm`, or `representedObject.numKm`.

How should I get around this?

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an easy problem. The thing is, Core Data doesn't know anything about `numKm` as a property. How is it supposed to know that `numKm` corresponds to a particular `CarProperty` object?

The fundamental problem you're describing is key-value coding compliance. Cocoa's going to look for a method called `numKm` on the `properties` object. Not finding one, it'll try sending `[properties valueForKey:@"numKm"];` Since `valueForKey:` doesn't know what to do with `numKm`, you get an error, but not before it calls `[properties valueForUndefinedKey:@"numKm"]`

But here's the catch: `properties` is an `NSSet` generated by Core Data, so you can't subclass it to override `valueForUndefinedKey:`. What you can do is create your own object that's KVC-compliant for your arbitrary properties and use that instead.

One solution is to subclass `NSDictionary` and make it act as a proxy. The primitive methods are `count`, `objectForKey:` and `keyEnumerator`. If you override these three methods, you can create an `NSDictionary` that's linked to your `Car` object and returns the appropriate `CarProperty` objects. For example:

```
@interface PropertyProxy : NSDictionary {
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) Car *car;

- (id)initWithCar:(Car *)car

@end

@implementation PropertyProxy

@synthesize car = _car;

- (id)initWithCar:(Car *)car {
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    _car = car;

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)count {
    return [car.properties count];
}

- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [[car.properties filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormt:@"key == %@", key]] anyObject];
}

- (NSEnumerator *)keyEnumerator {
    return [[car valueForKeyPath:@"properties.key"] objectEnumerator];
}

@end
```

Then, in your `Car` class, do this:

```
@interface Car : NSManagedObject {
    // other stuff
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *carProperties;

// other stuff

@end

@implementation Car

// other stuff

- (NSDictionary *)carProperties {
    return [[[PropertyProxy alloc] initWithCar:self] autorelease];
}

@end
```

(Disclaimer: I just typed this into my web browser, so no guarantees this actually compiles :-))

As you can see, it's not the easiest thing in the world to do. You'll be able to set up key paths like this:

```
representedObject.carProperties.numKm;
```

Keep in mind that, while this is key-value *coding* compliant, it is not key-value *observing* compliant. So if `numKm` changes, you won't be able to observe that. You would need to do some extra work to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks alot! That pointet me really much in a direction! Nice to know that i don't reinvent the weel on a common problem with a easy solution.

Comment: This answer is totally correct, however, I have to ask why are you using Core Data just to throw out it's power like this? If you have a car entity some things should really be attributes and other things should be relationships. For example numKm should just be either a float or int as it likely won't repeat between cars very often. The manufacturer on the other hand should totally be a relationship to a `Manufacturer` entity. THen you can even use bindings to view all cars from a particular manufacturer.

Comment: I can't speak to the OP's situation, but in mine, the properties aren't known until runtime. My app downloads lists of objects from a web server, where the lists can have arbitrary columns with abitrary types. Aside from a couple of properties that are guaranteed to exist and for which I did create properties, all the rest are variable in number and type.